# central element of order 2 belonging to G'

Tags: group-theory

Is it true that any central element of order 2 that belongs to the commutator subgroup G' of a group G must be equal to the unit of G?

Comment: The unit (identity?) of $G$ has order 1, right? So an element of order 2 cannot be the unit.

Comment: No it is not true. It is often wise to check the groups up to order 10 or 12 before asking a question.